# Failed to load a resource: The network connection was lost

Tags: browser, safari

The Safari 7 is unable to load our secure page. The developer tool shows the status code 200 but blank page is displayed. When we disabled the Java Script in browser then page loads properly. So we believe that there must be some problem in handling javascript in Safari 7. The console only displays:

**"Failed to load a resource: The network connection was lost."**

All other browsers are displaying the page properly.

Comment: A solution to a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46469548/1897218

Answer (score 0):

Finally we found a root cause of this issue.

The culprit was "Transfer-Encoding" response header. We disabled Chunking (Glassfish - Network config - click on http-listener - http tab) in Glassfish and it worked properly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: im facing exactly same one while redirecting to payment secure page from my angular application. its hosted in iis server. could you advise once, how to resolve for iis .