# Safari ajax request Failed to load resource: The network connection was lost

Tags: ajax, .htaccess, nginx, safari

I'm receiving a message ***"Failed to load resource: The network connection was lost."*** in my application, which uses ajax requests to get content from server. This error is only in Safari, other browsers are ok.

I was searching last few hours and found that it can be due to http headers:

*Transfer-Encoding : chunked

Connection: keep-alive

Content-Length*

I've found something similar: https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/7176
On the bottom is told that they set

**BrowserMatch "Safari" nokeepalive** 
 
in .htaccess.

Is there any similar solution or settings for nginx server?

Thank you

JF

Comment: **SOLVED**: changed the settings of nginx server. Added keepalive_disabled for safari in config. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#keepalive_disable

Comment: Had the same problem in an IOS cordova/phonegap app. Thanks!

Comment: @JakubFormanek Do we know the root cause of the issue? I see setting keepalive_disabled for safari solved the issue but do we iknow why its failing?

Comment: I am having the same issue. Is there any solution for apache2?

Comment: **Solved with Puma**: I had this problem with Safari when I made multiple AJAX requests and I have solved by removing the `queue_requests` from my Puma configuration. That option also has an effect on keepalive.

Answer (score 6):

One of the reasons why it might happen is the way Safari handles some SSL certificates (mainly, LetsEncrypt). The solution is to put the line:

`ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;`

to your nginx config.

Source: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/apple-safari-browsers-fail-to-connect/3731/3

Comment: omg I have been searching for this answer for one hour, why is it so obscurely documented?!

Comment: This all of the sudden starting happening on one of my app servers. Would an update from LetsEncrypt or my SSL certs cause this?

Comment: Actually, my issue wasnt SSL, it was the fact that some of the nginx files were owned by root user

Answer (score 0):

Had this trouble too with a form that ajax-posted and when that completed did a window.location.reload(true). Safari 13.0.3 would work the first time after a manual page refresh (seemed consistent) then would get "Failed to load resource: The network connection was lost." roughly 2 out of 3 clicks.

Changed the client to:

- use ajax-get instead of post (with a unique query param value each time)
- on completion set a timer so that window.location.reload(true) was not done inside the ajax completion handler

User reports that worked, not sure which one of those changes or both.

Hope this helps someone...