# Getting Axios network error on a delete request to a php server although CORS is set correctly

Tags: php, axios, cors

I'm trying to make GET,POST and DELETE requests to my api which is written in php from my client side which is in react. the problem is that when i make the Get request everything works fine but for Post and Delete request I get

> The network connection was lost.

followed by

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
> https://scandiweb-product-management.000webhostapp.com/api.php due to
> access control checks

The server is hosted on 000webhost.com and the front side is hosted on vercel. here is all my api.php

```
<?php
require_once('ProductFactory.php');

$db = new Database();

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    try{
        $selectedType = $data['type'];
        $values= $data['values'];
        $sku = $values['sku'];
        $name = $values['name'];

        $price = $values['price'];
        $size = $values['size'] ?? null;
        $weigth = $values['weigth'] ?? null;
        $width = $values['width'] ?? null;
        $length = $values['length'] ?? null;
        $heigth = $values['heigth'] ?? null;

        $stmt = $db->conn->prepare("SELECT sku FROM products WHERE sku = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $sku);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
            http_response_code(409);
            echo json_encode(["error" => "Product with SKU $sku already exists"]);
        } else {
            $product = ProductFactory::createProduct($sku, $name,$selectedType, $price, $size, $weigth, $heigth, $length, $width);

            if ($product !== null) {
                echo $product->save();
            } else {
                http_response_code(400); 
                echo json_encode(["error" => "Invalid product data provided"]);
            }
        }

        $stmt->close();

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        http_response_code(500);
        echo json_encode(["error" => "Internal Server Error"]);
    }

}


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
    $result = $db->conn->query("SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id ASC");

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $products = array();

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $id= $row['id'];
            $sku = $row['sku'];
            $name = $row['name'];
            $type = $row['type'];
            $price = $row['price'];
            $weigth = $row['weigth'];
            $size = $row['size'];
            $heigth = $row['heigth'];
            $length = $row['length'];
            $width = $row['width'];

            $products[] = array(
                'id'=>$id,
                'sku' => $sku,
                'name' => $name,
                'price' => $price,
                'type' => $type,
                'size'=> $size,
                'weigth'=> $weigth,
                'heigth'=> $heigth,
                'length'=> $length,
                'width'=> $width
            );
        }

        echo json_encode($products);
    } else {
        echo "No products found";
    }
}


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'DELETE') {
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

    $ids = $data['ids'] ?? [];

    if (!empty($ids)) {
         $deleted = 0;

         foreach ($ids as $id) {
            $stmt = $db->conn->prepare("DELETE FROM products WHERE id = ?");
            $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);

            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                $deleted++;
            }
        
            $stmt->close();
        }

         if ($deleted > 0) {
             echo "Deleted $deleted product(s) successfully";
         } else {
            echo "No products found for deletion";
         }
    } else {
        echo "No valid IDs provided";
    }
}
?>
```

and here is how im making the request for get and delete:

```
import { createContext , useState, useEffect} from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const productContext = createContext();
function Provider({children}){
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  const [currentPath, setCurrentPath] = useState(window.location.pathname);

  useEffect(()=> {
    const handler = () => {
      setCurrentPath(window.location.pathname)
    };
    window.addEventListener('popstate', handler);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('popstate', handler)
    };
  }, []);
  
  useEffect(()=> {
    fetchProducts();
  },[])
  
  const fetchProducts = async () => {
    const allProductsFromDb = await axios.get('https://scandiweb-product-management.000webhostapp.com/api.php');
    setProducts(allProductsFromDb.data); 
  };

  const deleteProducts = async (productIds) => {
    await axios.delete('https://scandiweb-product-management.000webhostapp.com/api.php',{data: {"ids": productIds}}).then(response => {
      console.log('Response:', response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error is:', error);
    });
    
    fetchProducts();
  };

  const navigate = (to) => {
      window.history.pushState({}, '', to);
      setCurrentPath(to);
  };

  const handlers = {
    products,
    fetchProducts,
    deleteProducts,
    currentPath,
    navigate
  };

  return (
  <productContext.Provider value= {handlers}>
    {children}
  </productContext.Provider>
  );
}

export {Provider}
export default productContext;
```

I have tried different states for CORS(specifying the exact client side address and different content allow headers) and nothing seems to solve the issue.Also on the local machine everything works fine regardless of method type.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49429778/5947043 might be relevant, as might other answers there, and elsewhere if you [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=XMLHttpRequest+cannot+load+due+to+access+control+checks). And which browser are you testing with? (Is it Safari?) Do you get the same error in others, or a different one? CORS errors usually have a bit more specific detail than that, in my experience.

Comment: P.S. While `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` is ok for testing maybe, it's not a great idea in a live environment. You're basically saying "I don't care who makes cross-origin requests to my site". Now _maybe_ your site doesn't  have anything sensitive in it where that could be an issue, but I still wouldn't really recommend it.

Comment: If this is indeed a Safari issue, https://stackoverflow.com/q/33895463/1427878 suggests that disabling HTTP Keep-Alive might help.

Comment: @ADyson I'm getting this error in chrome : {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …} followed by xhr.js:256 
 POST https://scandiweb-product-management.000webhostapp.com/api.php net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR
and the other one i mentioned in the post is in Safari

Comment: Thanks, this suggests that CORS is probably not the root cause of the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58215104/whats-the-neterr-http2-protocol-error-about may be useful . Since it's not your server though, you may need to ask for assistance from the hosting provider. If you're using one of those free hosting companies, well...you get what you pay for.

Comment: @ADyson yes i'm guessing it might a problem from the hosting site but i just tried firefox and the error is : Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://scandiweb-product-management.000webhostapp.com/api.php. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null). So this one is clearly pointing at CORS.

Comment: The _underlying_ reason for that though is likely to be if the remote server's code or environment crashed, and therefore couldn't return the necessary CORS headers. Have a look more closely in the Network tool to see what exactly the response from the server did look like

Comment: After trying it myself briefly, I _think_ what's happening is the server isn't responding properly to the preflight OPTIONS request which has to be made for a CORS POST or DELETE request. That could be the webserver config, if it doesn't pass that on to PHP, or doesn't respond at all to it

Comment: @ADyson the response header is empty in all 3 browsers network tab, so basically the server is not sending back any response for Delete and Post methods, whereas for Get it's sending back list of products as requested in the code.

Comment: Yes I know, that was also the result of my testing. In fact Chrome only shows provisional headers which suggests it can't even contact the server properly at all. I think that's for the reason I mentioned in my last comment. So it's likely something you need to raise with the hosting company, it seems they are not supporting OPTIONS requests properly. Like I said though, you get what you pay for, so I wish you luck getting them to co-operate or fix anything... if you're serious about your website you should put it onto a proper hosting company

Comment: @ADyson thanks for your help yes i have contacted them already, by the way can you recommend any good hosting websites that offer database storage too?

Comment: Almost all PHP hosts offer database functionality as well. There are hundreds. We don't provide product recommendations on Stackoverflow though, it's specifically [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). A lot of them are pretty similar, the difference being if you're paying for the product you tend to get much better reliability and technical support. Have a look around, examine product descriptions, and read some reviews, would be my advice.,

Comment: @ADyson ok i see, thanks alot.